# Stripe social security number nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

What parameter do I need to send social security numbers to Stripe when creating a Connected account?
I know how to send the last 4 but what about all of it?

```
try {
    const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'custom',
      country: 'US',
      email: "jake@gmail.com",
      business_type: 'individual',
      individual: {
        email: "jake@gmail.com",
        first_name: "Jake", 
        last_name: "Jake",
        ssn_last_4: "4241",
```

Comment: Then why I'm asked to provide it in the Dashboard of the connected accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to pass in [`id_number`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=node#create_account-individual-id_number) (which can be the full SSN) or a [PII token from Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=pii).